# Звёздный рейтинг на Font-awesome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
var __slice = [].slice;

(function($, window) {
    var Starrr;

    Starrr = (function() {
        Starrr.prototype.defaults = {
            rating: void 0,
            numStars: 5,
            change: function(e, value) {},
        };

        function Starrr($el, options) {
            var i, _, _ref,
                    _this = this;

            this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
            this.$el = $el;
            _ref = this.defaults;
            for (i in _ref) {
                _ = _ref[i];
                if (this.$el.data(i) != null) {
                    this.options[i] = this.$el.data(i);
                }
            }
            this.createStars();
            this.syncRating();
            this.$el.on('mouseover.starrr', 'i', function(e) {
                return _this.syncRating(_this.$el.find('i').index(e.currentTarget) + 1);
            });
            this.$el.on('mouseout.starrr', function() {
                return _this.syncRating();
            });
            this.$el.on('click.starrr', 'i', function(e) {
                return _this.setRating(_this.$el.find('i').index(e.currentTarget) + 1);
            });
            this.$el.on('starrr:change', this.options.change);
        }

        Starrr.prototype.createStars = function() {
            var _i, _ref, _results;

            _results = [];
            for (_i = 1, _ref = this.options.numStars; 1 <= _ref ? _i <= _ref : _i >= _ref; 1 <= _ref ? _i++ : _i--) {
                _results.push(this.$el.append("<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>"));
            }
            return _results;
        };

        Starrr.prototype.setRating = function(rating) {
            if (this.options.rating === rating) {
                rating = void 0;
            }
            this.options.rating = rating;
            this.syncRating();
            return this.$el.trigger('starrr:change', rating);
        };

        Starrr.prototype.syncRating = function(rating) {
            var i, _i, _j, _ref;

            rating || (rating = this.options.rating);
            if (rating) {
                for (i = _i = 0, _ref = rating - 1; 0 <= _ref ? _i <= _ref : _i >= _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
                    this.$el.find('i').eq(i).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
                }
            }
            if (rating && rating < 5) {
                for (i = _j = rating; rating <= 4 ? _j <= 4 : _j >= 4; i = rating <= 4 ? ++_j : --_j) {
                    this.$el.find('i').eq(i).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
                }
            }
            if (!rating) {
                return this.$el.find('i').removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
            }
        };

        return Starrr;

    })();
    return $.fn.extend({
        starrr: function() {
            var args, option;

            option = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
            return this.each(function() {
                var data;

                data = $(this).data('star-rating');
                if (!data) {
                    $(this).data('star-rating', (data = new Starrr($(this), option)));
                }
                if (typeof option === 'string') {
                    return data[option].apply(data, args);
                }
            });
        },
    });
})(window.jQuery, window);
```

Есть вот такой плагин под `jQuery`, взят с Гитхаба. он позволяет по `$(selector).starrr()`, создать звёздный рейтинг-бар, или что-то вроде того.

Как после того, как пользователь выбрал какое-то конкретное значение на этом баре, сделать сброс значения на нем? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: А почему у автора не спросить? Кстати, не плохо было бы добавить ссылку на github откуда взят

Comment: Спросил уже у автора, ответ нужен просто как можно скорее, поэтому решил запостить и здесь

Comment: https://github.com/dobtco/starrr

Comment: @bestervuld не могли бы вы пояснить, что значит сделать сброс?

Comment: обнулить значение этих зведочек до стандартного

Answer (score 5):

Посмотри данный вариант, я его использую обычно:

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

возможный вариант сброса, добавить после плагина или заменить в самом плагине setRating `this.options.rating = 0;`

```
window.Starrr.prototype.setRating = function(rating) {
  if (this.options.rating === rating) {
    rating = void 0;
  }
  this.options.rating = 0;
  this.syncRating();
  return this.$el.trigger('starrr:change', rating);
};
```