# Как сделать, что бы при нажатии на звезды рейтинга они остались желтого цвета?

Tags: css, jquery

Доделываю систему рейтинга комментариев в Wordpress. И есть вопрос по jQuery / CSS.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на звезды рейтинга, оставались желтого цвета, то количество, которое нажал пользователь. Как это лучше реализовать?

Посмотреть можно [тут](https://israel-escorts.com/profile/kira-hajfa-2/), прокрутить до формы комментирования.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556085/%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-font-awesome

Comment: В голову пришла мысль при нажатии менять фоновую картинку с тем количеством звёзд желтых, которое нажал посетитель, но по мне это решении времен IE6. Может кто-то посоветует лучше идею...

Comment: тут звёздный рейтинг уже пережёвывался мильён раз ...ссылку приложил на готовое решение ..оно не подходит ??

Comment: @MaximLensky это и есть решение моей проблемы: .rating > input:checked ~ label /* show gold star when clicked */ ?

Answer (score 3):

предлагаю такой вариант, собран из svg, значения берутся из первоначальной разметки (`value="1"`) и добавляются туда же

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.rating')].forEach(rating => {

    rating.innerHTML = '<svg width="110" height="20"></svg>';
    rating = rating.querySelector('svg');
    Array(5).fill(0).forEach((e,i) => {
        rating.innerHTML += `<polygon value="${i+1}"
           transform="translate(${i*22},0)" 
           points="10,1 4,19.8 19,7.8 1,7.8 16,19.8">`;
    }); 
    
    rating.onclick = function (e) {
        let v = e.target.getAttribute('value');
        v && rating.parentNode.setAttribute('value', v); 
        render();
        console.log(rating.parentNode)
    }; 
    
    render();
    
    function render(){
        let v = +rating.parentNode.getAttribute('value'); 
        [...rating.querySelectorAll('polygon')].forEach(s => {
            s.setAttribute('fill', v >= +s.getAttribute('value') 
                ? "gold" : "lightgray");
        })
    }
});
```

```css
.rating polygon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 500ms;
}
.rating polygon:hover{
    fill: black;
}
```

```html
<span class="rating"></span>
<span class="rating" value="1"></span>
<div class="rating" value="3"></div>
<div class="rating" value="5"></div>
```